# Do I have to export public GnuPG keys as well when exporting the private ones?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, gnupg

I created my GnuPG keys. They show up in my keys repository. Now I want to export my secret key and import it into another computer so I could use it on that computer (for example my laptop).

Do I have to export and import private and public keys separately? Does the secret key already include the public key somewhat?

Basically I want to have a copy of my public and private keys on my laptop.

Comment: Your private key should always remain private, you should not upload it to anywhere. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: Hi. I am not uploading it anywhere. I need to use it on my laptop as well.

Comment: Your public key goes on the server, the private key should **NEVER** leave your computer.  The way your question is worded leads me to belive you want to "export it and import it into another computer".

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [message](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-September/047729.html) in the GnuPG user group:

> If you import a secret key and you don't have the public key, GPG will
>   use the embedded public key data to recreate the public key, so
>   effectively an exported secret key is like exporting a key pair.

But it is a good idea to also send you public key with all signatures.

Also, you can consider submitting your key to a keyserver (such as the [SKS keyserver pool](https://sks-keyservers.net/)).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to export them separately; when exporting the secret key everything public is also contained. From [RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.5.1.3), highlighting added by me:

> #### 5.5.1.3.  Secret-Key Packet (Tag 5)

> A Secret-Key packet contains **all the information that is found in a
> Public-Key packet, including the public-key material**, but also
> includes the secret-key material after all the public-key fields.

You can also verify this by running `gpg --list-packets [file]`, which will dump a list of all contained packets including public (sub)keys, signatures etc.